# Счётчик для функции onEdit()

Tags: google-apps-script

Как добавить код счетчика для функции, который будет выводить в отдельной ячейке количество изменений в диапазоне, указанном в этой функции?

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var data, day, month; //Переменные для даты
  var sheet, col, row; //Преременные для работы с редакт. ячейками
  data = new Date();
  day = data.getDate();
  month = data.getMonth() + 1;
  sheet = e.source.getSheetByName("Лист2");
  col = e.range.getColumn();
  row = e.range.getRow();
  if (col == 6) {

    if (row > 3 && row < 15) {}


    sheet.getRange(row, 5).setValue(day + " " + month);

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Пример счетчика, который хранит значение в ячейке 'COUNTER'.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  try{
    // Do what you want
    conunter_(e.source);
  }catch(err){
    e.source.toast(err);
  }
}

function conunter_(spreadsheet, value){
  value = value || 1;
  var range_ = spreadsheet.getRange('COUNTER');
  var cur_ = range_.getValue();
  var res = cur_ + value;
  range_.setValue(res);
  return res;
}
```

Не основывайтесь на триггерах интерфейса. Они не гарантируют исполнение.

Comment: Спасибо Большое!

Comment: @МаксимБаринов, просто отметьте вопрос как решенный.